# What did Jack Ryan say in the missile room?

Tags: dialogue, the-hunt-for-red-october

Near the end of [The Hunt for Red October](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099810/), Jack Ryan...

> ...confronts the saboteur, a cook,...

...in the missile room. He says something in Russian, but there are no subtitles like earlier scenes.

What did he say?

Answer (score 3):

Well, we know (and they did not subtitle it) because he immediately repeats it, in English (I got the order wrong, he says the English, then the Russian, thanks to TJL.

> a goddamn cook!

**Except that, no, we don't actually know that.**  I always assumed he was repeating/translating for the English-speaking movie audience. Here's what I found when trying to find citations/references to back up that mistaken assumption:

Looking at scripts - none of the original scripts have any reference to dialogue there.  There are no words spoken.  What *is* interesting in the scripts is that

> the agent/cook is holding two wires, gleefully evil as he prepares to bring them together with, it is assumed, disastrous consequences.

[IMSDb: Script for The Hunt For Red October](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Hunt-for-Red-October,-The.html)

Others have asked this question.  On a couple of different message board threads on the Straight Dope website, users have supplied this answer, which fits with description of the actions the original script:

> Where's what Baldwin says, in Russian -
>
> "Ostav' eto v pokoye!"
>
> Literal translation is "Leave it in peace!" the closest English translation is "Leave it alone!"

[The Straight Dope Message Boards: What did Alec Baldwin say in Russian?](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=79279)

Or, in this case, essentially, "Drop it!"

Answer (score 0):

Literal translations of Eastern Slavic are seldom correct because much of the conversation is implied by context. In this case Jack Ryan is saying to GRU Officer Loganov, ”Оставь это в покое!” (Ostav’ eto v pokoye) or “Put it down calmly!” The literal translation is actually “Leave it in peace!”

Similarly, when Dr Petrov says “Капитан в бою!” (Kapitan v boyu) the subtitle reads “The Captain is fighting the Americans!” but literally translates to “Captain in battle.”

Comment: @Joachim There was no accepted answer at the time of this post. The older answer is roughly half irrelevant, so it never got the check..